# apply chain rule to get this result

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

Given
$$
g(\tau_e, t, \vec x, \vec \zeta) \equiv \tau_e - t + \frac{1}{c_0} |\vec x - \vec y(\vec \zeta, \tau_e)| = 0
$$

The textbook "Aeroacoustics" said applying for chain rule, will have
$$
\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_j}\right)_{\tau_e=const} + \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial \tau_e}\right)_{\vec x=const}\frac{\partial \tau_e}{\partial x_j}
=0$$

How did it come?

Comment: You can get parentheses (and other paired delimiters) to adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: What's being held constant in $\frac{\partial\tau_e}{\partial x_j}$?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by $\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_j}\right)_{\tau_e=\text{const}}$ when $g$ depends on further variables beyond $\vec x$ and $\tau_e$?

Comment: @joriki, thanks for the comments! For your second, question, it was not written in the textbook...I copied exactly what has been said in the textbook to here.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it was because

assuming $$\vec y = \text{const}$$ $$ \vec \zeta = \text{const}$$

so consider $\tau_e$ as a function of $x_j$, the result is the got.

Comment: I think it's best to add this to the question, instead of answering.